# XPath testing that string ends with substring?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, ends-with

Given that the HTML contains:

```
  <div tagname="779853cd-355b-4242-8399-dc15f95b3276_Destination" class="panel panel-default"></div>
```

How do we write the following expression in XPath:

***Find a `<div>` element whose `tagname` attribute ends with the string 'Destination'***

I've been searching for days and I can't come up with something that works. Among many, I tried for example:

```
div[contains(@tagname, 'Destination')]
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### XPath 2.0

```
//div[ends-with(@tagname, 'Destination')]
```

### XPath 1.0

```
//div[substring(@tagname, string-length(@tagname) 
                          - string-length('Destination') + 1)  = 'Destination']
```

Comment: 1.0 Version saved me, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

XPath 2 or 3: There's always regex.

```
.//div[matches(@tagname,".*_Destination$")]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ends-with` (Xpath 2.0)

```
//div[ends-with(@tagname, 'Destination')]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the below xpath which will work with Xpath 1.0

`//div[string-length(substring-before(@tagname, 'Destination')) >= 0 and  string-length(substring-after(@tagname, 'Destination')) = 0 and contains(@tagname, 'Destination')]`

Basically it checks if there is any string ( or no strings ) before the first occurrence of `Destination` but there should not be any text after the `Destination`

Test input :

```
<root>
<!--Ends with Destination-->
<div tagname="779853cd-355b-4242-8399-dc15f95b3276_Destination" class="panel panel-default"></div>
<!--just Destination-->
<div tagname="Destination" class="panel panel-default"></div>
<!--Contains Destination-->
<div tagname="779853cd-355b-4242-8399-dc15f95b3276_Destination_some_text" class="panel panel-default"></div>
<!--Doesn't contain destination-->
<div tagname="779853cd-355b-4242-8399-dc15f95b3276" class="panel panel-default"></div>
</root>
```

Test output:

```
<div class="panel panel-default"
     tagname="779853cd-355b-4242-8399-dc15f95b3276_Destination"/>
<div class="panel panel-default" tagname="Destination"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you have landed on this discussion for a [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) or [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) based solution, [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) still supports only [xpath-1.0](/questions/tagged/xpath-1.0) where **`ends-with()`** isn't supported.

---

### Solution

Given the HTML:

```
<div tagname="779853cd-355b-4242-8399-dc15f95b3276_Destination" class="panel panel-default"></div>
```

Using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/#xpath) a potential solution would be to use the `contains()` method as follows:

```
//div[contains(@tagname, 'Destination')]
```

Accomodating the *`class`* attributes:

```
//div[contains(@tagname, 'Destination') and @class='panel panel-default']
```

Comment: **Warning:** `contains()` is a poor substitute for `ends-with()` because `contains()` will match *anywhere*, not just at the end.   Better to use the [more verbose idiom for `ends-with()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40935676/290085) if limited to XPath 1.0.

Comment: As long as I have an attribute, which does not contain whitespaces (like `id` or the mentioned `tagname`), I just append a whitespace and use contains: `//div[contains(concat(@id, ' '), '_myIdSuffix_ ')]`, or in response to the question: `//div[contains(concat(@tagname, ' '), 'Destination ')]`

Answer (score -1):

Another solution that is XPath 1.0 compatible:

```
//div[contains(concat(@tagname, 'UNIQUE'), concat('Destination', 'UNIQUE'))]
```

I used this while searching for entries in a KeePass Database using the XPath expression search feature:

```
//Entry/String[contains(concat(Key, 'UNIQUE'), '/UNIQUE')]
```

found all entries that have a custom string field that ends in '/'.