# starts with and ends with in xpath

Tags: xpath, beautifulsoup, ixmldomelement

Following is how the element looks like on the page:

[image]

I want all the *li* which comes right after *General Engineering Courses*. *General* [COURSE_NAME] *Courses* is common text on other pages as well.

So basically I want all the *li* which come right after *GENERAL* [COURSE_NAME] *Courses*.

I wrote the following XPath, but unfortunately, it's causing DOMException while executing the XPath on Chrome.

```
//*[starts-with(text(), 'GENERAL') and ends-with(text(), 'COURSES')]
```

[image]

Page: http://catalog.fullerton.edu/content.php?catoid=16&navoid=1922

Comment: Duplicate of [XPath for element whose attribute value ends with a specific string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40934644/xpath-for-element-whose-attribute-value-ends-with-a-specific-string)

Comment: `ends-with()` requires XPath 2.0, and browsers only support XPath 1.0.  See duplicate link for a work-around.

Comment: Try `//*[starts-with(text(), 'GENERAL') and substring(text(), string-length(text()) - string-length('COURSES') +1) = 'COURSES']`

Answer (score 0):

You need use XPath Axes, the following-sibling

```
//p[starts-with(strong,'GENERAL ') and substring(strong, string-length(strong)-7)=' COURSES']/following-sibling::ul/li
```