# XPath for HTML, only those elements with certain words needed

Tags: html, xml, parsing, dom, xpath

I have this HTML document,
I want to XPath in headless Chrome to simulate click of all PDF links.
For that I should find all "href" that contains: documents , `budget-2020-21 OR budget-2020-2021`
also ends with .pdf

Here is an example HTML markup:

```html
<a href="https://www.website.com/documents/7-2045/budget-address-budget-2020-21-en.pdf"
<a href="https://www.website.com/documents/7-2045/crown-corporation-business-plans-budget-2020-21-en.pdf"
<a href="https://www.website.com/documents/7-2045/estimates-supplementary-detail-budget-2020-21-en.pdf" 
<a href="https://www.website.com/documents/7-2045/budget-2020-21-government-business-plan.pdf" 
<a href="https://www.website.com/documents/7-2045/highlights-budget-2020-21-en.pdf"
<a href="https://www.website.com/documents/7-2045/presentation-slides-budget-2020-21-en.pdf" 
<a href="https://www.website.com/sites/default/files/documents/6-2046/ftb-bfi-041-en-budget-2020-2021.pdf">
```

I used this XPath expression:

```
//*[contains(@href,’budget-2020-21 OR budget-2020-2021’)]
```

It seems OR is not correctly used. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath is selecting all elements with an attribute value that contains the substring, `'budget-2020-21 OR budget-2020-2021'`, literally.

If you want all elements with an attribute value that contains the substring, `'budget-2020-21'` or `'budget-2020-2021'`

```
//*[contains(@href,'budget-2020-21') or contains(@href,'budget-2020-2021')]
```

Note also that you must use single quote, `'`, or double quote, `"`, characters to delimit the string literals, not grave accent, `’`, as you have in the XPath in your question.

### See also

- [XPath testing that string ends with substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40934644/290085)

Comment: Sorry , It seems your Xpath expression  didn't highlight those pdf links:                                       //*[contains(@href,'budget-2020-21') or contains(@href,'budget-2020-2021')]

Comment: It most certainly does select those `a` elements, once you fix them to be well-formed.  (Scroll to the right to see that the `a` elements you posted are missing `>` and `</a>`.)  Then, you should be able to add a `[ ]` filter to require ending with `".pdf"` using the how-to link I provided.

Comment: Please [**accept**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's solved your problem.   If not, please follow-up specifically so any outstanding concerns can be addressed.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes Your answer looks correct, so that is why I upvoted it back in January.  I have decided to start taking the position of your last comment on my answers.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex: Thanks for the upvote, but I'm confused:  Is tursunWali another account of yours?  (If not, I'm wondering why you're responding here.)  I was guiding tursunWali to accept this answer if it resolves the issue or follow-up with a comment explaining how the problem remains if unresolved.

Comment: I responded because I always walk through the history of other posts for an OP that I have answered a question for.  I do this, because I'm trying to understand an OP, so I can response to their question better.