# Wild card in element selector XPath

Tags: html, css, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have the following XPath

```
//*[@href="/slug1/30/slug2/slug3/slug4" and normalize-space(text())="Push"]
```

The 30 is dynamic and changes so need this wildcard

E.g

```
//*[@href="/dashboard/*/zones/vod/push" and normalize-space(text())="Push"]
```

but this does not seem to work.

Any ideas how to get wildcard for this XPath?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match any element in an XPath itself, `*` would be fine, but you're looking to match any substring in text.  In XPath 1.0, you can use `starts-with()` and the [XPath 1.0 equivalent of `ends-with()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40934644/290085).

Since you can use XPath 2.0, use `matches()` to match a regex.

For one or more characters in the wildcard position, use `.+`:

```
//*[matches(@href,"/slug1/.+/slug2/slug3/slug4") and normalize-space(text())="Push"]
```

For digits only there, use `\d+`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which programming language you are using, I believe it is xslt.

As per my understanding you can use wild cards for input tags but not for values of the tags.

I would suggest to use contains functionality in xslt by slipting the value to use using string functionality and validate