# XPath for id attribute with changing substring in middle?

Tags: html, xml, dom, xpath

I have a website I need to isolate XPATH identifiers on - they have an XPath ID like this `//*[@id="panel-detail-6163748c7952a-partnerCode"]`

The issue is that the website changes the value `6163748c7952a` on every page load.

Is there any such XPath expression which can match on the first/last part of that string? So of a wildcard like `//*[@id="panel-detail-*-partnerCode"]`

Comment: xpath 2 supports regular expressions.  What version of xpath processor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This **XPath 2.0** expression,

```
//*[matches(@id, "^panel-detail-.*-partnerCode$")]
```

or this **XPath 1.0** expression,

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'panel-detail-') and
    substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('-partnerCode') + 1)  
                                                    = '-partnerCode']
```

will match all elements whose `id` attribute value starts and ends with the noted substrings.

**See also**

- [XPath testing that string ends with substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40934644/290085)

Answer (score 0):

There are few methods in xpath such as `starts-with` or `ends-with`. Many time folks replaces them with contains which should be discourage.

Please note that ends-with is available with `xpath  v2.0` .

**xpath v1.0 :**

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'panel-detail-') and contains(@id, '-partnerCode')]
```

**xpath v2.0 :**

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'panel-detail-') and ends-with(@id, '-partnerCode')]
```

Comment: In what way does your answer offer anything beyond that which I'd already answered four hours prior?

Comment: I believe readability.

Comment: Well, the XPath 1.0 workaround in my answer for the lack of `ends-with()` is hard to read, but it's a standard idiom to achieve the same result.   I was just surprised to see you acknowledge that `contains()` should be discouraged in its place as it could also match other than at the end, and then go ahead and use it in your answer anyway.

Comment: @kjhughes : I agree with you that `contains` should be avoided and should have been avoided. But in xpath 1.0 I really do not know how to parse the end sub-string.

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69519938/290085) and the referenced Q/A therein for how to effectively do `ends-with()` in XPath 1.0.