# Can ends-with() and text() be combined in XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, text, ends-with

Already tried `//*[ends-with(text()='updated the meeting')]` and `//*[ends-with(text(),'updated the meeting')]` but did not work.

[image: no element match]

Comment: Please always include a [mcve] with your data included in the question as text, never as an image.  This will allow us and future readers to search, copy, paste, and verify answers.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `ends-with()` and `text()` can be used together in XPath, but...

- No, it won't work the way you're trying.
- No, using `normalize-space()` (as other answerers are offering) is
  not the way to work around the problem; such "solutions" do
  not test for the presence of a substring *at the end of another string*.

**First issue:** `ends-with()` requires XPath 2.0.  If you're stuck with XPath 1.0, [here's the (verbose) workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40935676/290085).

**Second issue:** Even if your processor supports XPath 2.0, passing `text()` as its first argument is a mistake because `ends-with()` expects a string as its first argument, not a sequence of text nodes.  [This common confusion also occurs in XPath with the `contains()` function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255563/290085)

Therefore, to select all elements whose last text node child ends with `'updated the meeting'`, you need to use this XPath 2.0 expression:

```xml
//*[text()[last()][ends-with(.,'updated the meeting')]]
```

To ignore any possible trailing whitespace:

```xml
//*[text()[last()][ends-with(normalize-space(),'updated the meeting')]]
```

Conversion of the above XPath 2.0 expressions to XPath 1.0 [using this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40935676/290085) is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `normalize-space()`  method here:

```xml
//*[normalize-space() = 'updated the meeting']
```

or

```xml
//span[normalize-space() = 'updated the meeting']
```

The solutions above will work here, but in case there was some text before `updated the meeting` like `more text presenting, updated the meeting` you could use this:

```xml
//*[ends-with(normalize-space(text()), 'updated the meeting']
```

or this

```xml
//span[ends-with(normalize-space(text()), 'updated the meeting']
```

Please take in account that `ends-with` is not supported by XPath 1.0

Comment: or `//*[ends-with(normalize-space(text()), 'updated the meeting']`

Comment: You are right, thanks @MadsHansen. I will update the answer. But my original answer is enough here.

Comment: You should mention that ends-with will not work with XPath 1.0

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the picture, ends-with will not work. This is the `text()` value including the new lines and the quotes

```
xmllint --shell test.html 
/ > cat //div/span/text()
 -------

  " updated the meeting"
```

Adding `normalize-space()`

```
xmllint --xpath 'normalize-space(//div/span/text())'  test.html ; echo
" updated the meeting"
```

Using `contains()`

```
xmllint --xpath '//*[contains(normalize-space(text()), "updated the meeting")]'  test.html ; echo
<span>
  " updated the meeting"
  </span>
```