# How to make an XPath which contains both starts-with and not end-with attribute?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, element

I need to make an XPath.

I am writing a script and trying to get an exact element from the page.

Comment: Something like `//element[boolean(@starts-with) and not boolean(@end-with)]`? Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example demonstrating the HTML or XML that you are trying to target and better explain what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) supports [xpath-1.0](/questions/tagged/xpath-1.0)

Where as [`ends-with()`](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/xpath-ends-with/) isn't part of **xpath v1.0** but a part of [**xpath v2.0**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40935676/7429447) specifications.

Hence, you can't use the *`ends-with()`* clause directly.