# xpath ends-with text not a valid XPath expression

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to get elements with inner text that start with `A new payment` and end with `was created`.

```html
<span>A new payment pi_123432 for $40.03 USD was created</span>
```

```js
var xpath = "//span[starts-with(text(), 'A new payment') and ends-with(text(), 'was created')]";
var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```

I'm getting `not a valid XPath expression`

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[starts-with(text(), 'A new payment') and ends-with(text(), 'was created')]' is not a valid XPath expression.`

When I break it down this xpath works:

```
var xpath = "//span[starts-with(text(), 'A new payment')]";
```

But this xpath throws the same error

```
var xpath = "//span[ends-with(text(), 'was created')]"
```

But I can't tell why.

I'm on chrome.

Comment: ends-with is valid on XPath 2.0 which browser might not support. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40935676/2834978

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xpath "ends-with" does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436789/xpath-ends-with-does-not-work)

Comment: If you need XPath 2.0 (or 3.0, or 3.1) in the browser, try SaxonJS.

Answer (score 1):

`ends-with` is only in Xpath 2.0 and chrome uses Xpath 1.0

### Xpath 1.0

```js
var xpath = "//span[starts-with(text(), 'A new payment') and substring(text(), string-length(text()) - string-length('was created') + 1)  = 'was created']";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [SaxonJS 2](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml) and XPath 3.1:

```js
var xpath = "//span[starts-with(., 'A new payment') and ends-with(., 'was created')]";
var matchingElements = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(xpath, document, { xpathDefaultNamespace : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' });

console.log(matchingElements);
```

```html
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/Saxon-JS-2.4/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>

<span>A new payment pi_123432 for $40.03 USD was created</span>
```

See also the [download page](https://www.saxonica.com/download/javascript.xml) and the [documentation of SaxonJS](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

> But this xpath throws the same error
>
> ```
> var xpath = "//span[ends-with(text(), 'was created')]"
> ```
>
> But I can't tell why.

[***fn:ends-with()***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-ends-with) appeared for the first time in the ***[XPath 2.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/)***. It isn't a standard XPath 1.0 function.

**In XPath 1.0 to find the value of `ends-with($s, $suffix)` use**:

```
substring($s, string-length($s) - string-length($suffix) + 1) =  $suffix
```