# How to find an element in Selenium (Python) using ends with and click the corresponding radio button?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver, webdriverwait

I want to click the radio button of the item that matches my grant number. The issue is that the HTML seems to have some numbers before it that I don't know until I search. For example, if I search for `ABC-2202`, the HTML might look something like this:

```
<input type="Radio" name="PanelGroup" id="PanelGroup" value="225,ABC-2202" title="Panel Group">
```

I want to find and click the radio button that **ends with** my phrase because there also exists some results like `ABC-2202-A`, `ABC-2202-B`, etc.

I have already tried the following (which I found in other questions on Stackoverflow), with the variable:

```
grant = 'ABC-2202'
```

then

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[substring(@value, string-length(@value) - string-length(grant) +1) = grant]".click()
```

and

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='radio'][value$=grant]").click()
```

but neither of these has worked for me.

Comment: How many buttons are there?  Can't you use `find_elements` for all `<input>` tags and just search the `value` attribute yourself?

Comment: contains or ends-with should work... see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40934644/xpath-testing-that-string-ends-with-substring

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) still supports only [xpath-1.0](/questions/tagged/xpath-1.0) where [`ends-with()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76559586/7429447) isn't supported.

---

### Solution

Given the following HTMLs:

```
<input type="Radio" name="PanelGroup" id="PanelGroup" value="225,ABC-2202" title="Panel Group">
```

and

```
<input type="Radio" name="PanelGroup" id="PanelGroup" value="ABC-2202-A" title="Panel Group">
```

and

```
<input type="Radio" name="PanelGroup" id="PanelGroup" value="ABC-2202-B" title="Panel Group">
```

Using Selenium to identify the element where the value attribute ends with *`ABC-2202`* a potential solution would be to use a [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447) as follows:

```
input[value$='ABC-2202']
```

Accomodating the other attributes:

```
input#PanelGroup[value$='ABC-2202'][type='Radio'][name='PanelGroup'][title='Panel Group']
```

---

Ideally, to click on the **clickable** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#PanelGroup[value$='ABC-2202'][type='Radio'][name='PanelGroup'][title='Panel Group']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```